# Backup and restore apps deleted from Store

Tags: apps, backup

My Lumia 920 is currently running the Black firmware, with the Windows Phone 8.1 Developer Preview. Other Lumia 920 owners in the household, previously running 8.0 on Black, were able to upgrade to Cyan with 8.1 today. From online searching, it appears that the only current way for me to get Cyan is to use a Nokia tool to wipe the phone and restore it with 8.0.

However, I have some apps installed which appear to be currently removed from the Store. I would like to be able to re-install these apps after the wipe & update if at all possible. Is there a way that I can back up all of the apps installed on my phone (or, at least, the ones that didn't come bundled with the OS/firmware) and then manually re-install them later?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to export or extract an installed app from Windows Phone.

The only way to install an app that's not longer on the Windows Phone store is to have a copy of the XAP file, which can then be manually installed later.

Another option would be to contact the app developer directly and see if they will re-issue the app, or have a copy of the XAP from the store.

Comment: So, no way to get the XAP file off the phone?

Comment: @Iszi no, technically when an app is installed, the files are stored in a folder. There is no XAP at that point.

Answer (score -1):

If you download all of the files from the install folder, zip them up and rename the file extension to .XAP that ought to work. You may need to delete the file WMAppPRHeader.xml before you zip the files.

Comment: How do you suggest downloading all the files from the install folder?