# Get rid of applications, that were removed from App Store

Tags: apps, backup, app-update

I have received "cleared" Lumia 535 from service, after two week long fixup. Since phone was restored to factory defaults, first thing, that I did was to login to my Microsoft account and restore all the settings applications etc.

Phone has restored all my previously backed up applications, including two apps (one game and one unknown app) that are no longer available in App Store.

Because of that, I can't do actually anything with them. I have them listed in app list under `#` as `Downloading application` / `attention required` and in App Store app, in `downloads` section on list titled `action needed` plus, again `Attention required. Tap here.`. But, when tapping such item, I don't have many options: `close`, that does nothing, `try again`, that also does nothing, because apps shifts to `pending` list for 2-3 seconds and then goes back to `action needed`. I also have `Release notes` link, which links to application details, but shows no actual info and pops with `Item not available` / `This item isn't available in the Store` error message after 2-3 seconds.

What can I do with such applications? How to uninstall them or get rid of them from my phone?

BTW: [This answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/5608/11237) does not solve my problem, because I neither have `.xap` file for that missings apps nor I even know they names, so I can't contact their vendor / developer.

Comment: Do you get any options if you press and hold on their entries on the start menu?

Comment: Yes: `Share` and `Retry`. Effect on using `Retry` is described in question. Using `Share` in this scenario (get rid of the app) brings no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, that such "missing" application needs some time in Windows Phone to "mature enough", so Windows can start treating it as "gone". In my case, I had to **wait two days** (no phone restart in between), since initial backup's restore, to finally see `Cancel Download` item in long-tap menu for each application. I'm more than sure, that there was no such item right after restore.

In addition, since my phone was long time in service, I had troubles recognizing, which applications are these two, that are gone. And Windows doesn't help, as it does not provide you with "missing" application name, neither on apps list in home screen nor in `Download` list in App Store.

It turned out, that for one application, I could help myself recognizing it, by using... `Share` item from long-tap menu. For some strange reason, when used with `Mail` option (sharing app info through e-mail) Windows managed to discover correct application name and even link to Windows Market. Why that worked only for one of two applications on topic and why Windows was able to reveal app name only after using `Share` menu, not directly on apps list -- will remain a sweet mystery of Microsoft and is beyond my imagination.

Answer (score 1):

if you go into your apps list (swipe left from home screen) if you press and hold on the application in question you can select "uninstall"

[image]

Comment: Per the comment on the question, the only options visible in this situation where `Share` and `Retry`

Comment: thats in the downloads section, which isnt where you delete the application from.

Comment: I don't know, if I explained that in enough details in my question, but believe me, if there would be any trace or sign of `Uninstall`, `Remove`, `Delete` or `Cancel` item in any menu on any list, I assure you, that I would make use of it instead of wasting my time for asking. So no, there was no such item.

Comment: How odd.  All applications have that option for me.  What OS version are you using?

Comment: If the app isn't installed in the first place you won't have the option to uninstall it...

Comment: I'm using newest version of Windows available for Lumia 535. I don't know, which exactly, but for sure it is newest one, because my phone has just got back from the repair and the only operation made there was installing the newest available version of OS. And, yes, Shawn is right. Since these applications were not installed, but "got back from backup", then there was no `Uninstall` option for the first two days.